# Make the forward counter go down

Tags: circuits, digital-circuits

Suppose, I have a 4-bit binary Incrementor that uses XOR gates to increment the inputted number by the value of 1 (b0001, to be precise).

Suppose, we connect it to 4 D-Flip-Flops (DFF) to create a counter that goes up every time we send the clock pulse. This is straightforward: Just connect the outputs of DFFs to the corresponding inputs of the Incrementor, and the outputs of the incrementor—to the corresponding inputs of the DFFs.

What I would like to figure out is how to alter the set up in order to make the counter go down instead of up at the flip of the up/down switch (e.g., goes down every time we send the clock pulse and the up/down switch is activated). I would prefer a walk through the entire process instead of just a ready answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what happens when you add $2^4$ each clock tick? What about $2^4-1$? How can you implement this (efficiently)?

You can also solve this in general: what happens when you add $2^n-1$ for an $n$-bit number? What would be the general way to implement this?